# T-SQL script needed to extract the content from xml value stored in the database

Tags: sql-server-2008

The value stored in the database is in the below format

```
<xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      Please verify the username: ...
    </xsl:template>
```

I need to extract the text "Please verify the username: ..." ie the text inside the `<xsl:template>` tag using SQL Server 2008. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If this was valid and well-formed Xml, you could do it using Xml functionality and data types but since it is formatted as just a fragment I would use basic string functions.

There are about three ways I can think to do this. Here is one overly basic way. It just uses the knowledge you already have about the text you have, the Xml tags, and some string functions.

The output of the code below is "Please verify the username: ..." or whatever you place within those tags.

Again; it's not the most elegant but it does work for what you described.

```
--string to search
DECLARE @xml AS nvarchar(500) = N'
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  Please verify the username: ...
</xsl:template>'

--SELECT @xml
DECLARE @startTag AS varchar(50) = '%<xsl:template match="/">%'
DECLARE @endTag AS varchar(50) = '%</xsl:template>%'

/* you can now find the to start and end positions for the tags and parse it out*/
DECLARE @parsedContent AS varchar(250)
SET @parsedContent = REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@xml,PATINDEX(@startTag, @xml),   (PATINDEX(@endTag, @xml) + 15)),'<xsl:template match="/">',''),'</xsl:template>','')

SELECT @parsedContent
```